# jquery filter selector vs filter method

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with getting the jquery filter method to work.

If I have

```
$("#resultDiv tr:odd").addClass("alternate_row");
```

All of the rows within the div "resultDiv" that contains a table are given the alternate row class.

However if i use

```
 $('#resultDiv').filter("tr:odd").addClass("alternate_row");
```

It doesn't appear to match any elements and nothing has the class applied.

I need to use the filter method as I'm doing a few other things passing variables around.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just as a thought, if you're trying to add the classes for styling purposes (like zebra striping) and you don't have to support older browsers, you can also look into the CSS3 nth-child selector.

Comment: unfortunately we do have to support older browsers which is why I chose to go this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first version:

> `$('#resultDiv').filter("tr:odd").addClass("alternate_row")`

`.filter()` *removes* non-matching elements from a set, and none of your `#resultDiv` elements are `tr`, so the filter doesn't match anything.

Try:

```
$('#resultDiv').find("tr:odd").addClass("alternate_row");
```

which explicitly *adds* new descendent nodes that *match* the `tr:odd` selector, or

```
$('#resultDiv tr').filter(":odd").addClass("alternate_row");
```

which uses a single selector to find *all* `tr` elements, and then uses `.filter` to only pick the odd ones.

Comment: @DanielPowell  in your question?  Because the first selector explicitly finds the descendent `tr` nodes.  `.filter()` doesn't _find_ new nodes, it only reduces the currently matched set.

Answer (score 5):

With the second selector you're selecting the element with the id `#resultDiv` and apply filter to it. But it's probably not a collection, just a table or something.

You have to select `tr` elements and apply filter to them like this;

```
$('#resultDiv tr').filter(":odd").addClass("alternate_row");
```

This way you'll have a `tr` collection to apply a filter.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that `#resultDiv` is the parent of all the `<tr>`'s so I think you want this:

```
$('#resultDiv tr').filter(":odd").addClass("alternate_row");
```